# amazon aws are very very slow, mysql and apache eat a lot of memeory

Tags: mysql, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mysql-workbench

I am using amazon aws ec2, its very very slow. I don't know where is wrong.

I am using `free` and `top` command, and found `mysql` and `apache` using lots of memory.

[image: free -m]

Here  is `top -M`

[image: top -M]

I found that `apache` and `mysql` eat more.

Here is apache info:

```
[ec2-user@www ****]$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (Amazon)
Server built:   Sep 20 2013 18:01:06
```

Mysql info:

```
Server version: 5.5.34 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

I am not modify any mysql & apache configuration file , what should I do next ?
Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: This all looks perfectly normal.  You have plenty of free memory, and the "cached" memory is essentially also free memory, and you aren't swapping.  You also show no iowait.  You'll need to be more specific on what "slow" means, because there's nothing here that I see, that would indicate any problems.  MySQL and Apache both do tend to use and hold on to a lot of memory, in order to *improve* their performance.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks reply, slow means,my site are very very very slow, when I visit it.

Comment: well then, you're not visiting in the metrics you show :)  May I suggest trying new relic?  I think they do a free month and it really helps for analyzing bottle necks.  You have given us basically nothing to work with - you've said your server is too slow, said (incorrectly) that things are using lots of memory, and then shown us information depicting a completely idle and memory-abundant system.  What is your site running?

Comment: What stack are you running for your application?

Comment: Voted to close. This question is completely off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown us any reason to think this is slow.  What you *have* shown us is that almost *all* of your memory is free and that your CPUs, from the picture, are idle.

When analyzing memory usage, remember that "cached" memory is used to hold things that were retrieved from the hard drive.  Rather than free that memory and then waste it, the linux kernel smartly leaves the data in memory, clearing it out when necessary.  This is a good thing - it means that many things, eg mysql data files, live in memory whenever possible.  Caching files in memory is a great thing!  You actually have over 6 gigs free.

The VIRT memory in top is basically meaningless - ignore it.  See https://serverfault.com/questions/138427/top-what-does-virtual-memory-size-mean-linux-ubuntu  What you should be looking at is RES - and 256M for mysql and a few dozen megs for Apache and mod-php is pretty nominal.  In fact, for the server you appear to have ( Large with 7 gigs of memory) if you have more than 200 megs or so of data in your database ,you should probably use *more* of it for mysql, as it would yeild great performance gains.

If your site is slow, it's not because of memory.

A few questions to consider to determine likely performance bottlenecks:

- what instance type are you using?
- is it Ephemeral backed, or EBS Backed?
- do you see spikes in Wait time when the server is being "slow"?
- What php application are you running?

AWS instances often are underpowered for their memory and ephemeral storage.  For example large instances have 7 gigs of ram, but only 2, 2ghz circa 2007 processors.  So they're not fast by any means.  The c1 and m3 line of instances do much to improve on this.

Comment: thanks Dan, I've fixted my problem.

Comment: So what was the issue?  maybe somebody else can learn!

Comment: I have a sql query performance problem. Not the mem or cpu problem. Thanks.